# Sdkmanager version package not signed

Tags: android, gradle, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I use gradle with Docker and Jenkins. Since January 11 I have this error on my project : `Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted. platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28`

But when I lauch `sdkmanager --licences` I have this output : `All SDK package licenses accepted.`

I think my `licences` is expired. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue open for it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123054726

As a workaround I installed it individually. i.e.

```
$ yes | $ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platforms;android-28"
```